# How can I add four CNN models after a convolution layer? And how can I connect then in a full-connected layer?

Tags: python, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

The first layer is called the global convolution layer donated as G-conv1. It is then divided into four equal parts, denoted as Pi-conv1, where i = {1, . . . , 4}. Each Pi-conv1 forms the first layer of an independent body-part channel, which is followed by a body-part convolution layer denoted as Pi-conv2, and a channel-wise full connection layer denoted as Pi-fc. The full-body channel consists of max pooling of G-conv1 denoted as Bpool1, full-body convolution layer denoted as B-conv2, another max pooling denoted as B-pool2, and a channel-wise fully connection layer denoted as B-fc. The network-wise full connection layer is denoted as N-fc.

[image]

Comment: What deep learning framework are you using?

Comment: @rayryeng hello~ I used keras